# Проблема при подключении библиотеки в Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dom, package

При подключении библиотеки dom4j-1.6.1.jar в Intelij IDEA вроде всё хорошо, но при компиляции следующего класса выдает ошибку.

```
package com.tutorialspoint.xml;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

public class DOM4JParserDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File(("src/com/tutorialspoint/xml/input.txt"));
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
            Document document = reader.read( inputFile );

            System.out.println("Root element :" + document.getRootElement().getName());

            Element classElement = document.getRootElement();

            List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/class/student" );
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            for (Node node : nodes) {
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getName());
                System.out.println("Student roll no : " + node.valueOf("@rollno") );
                System.out.println("First Name : " + node.selectSingleNode("firstname").getText());
                System.out.println("Last Name : " + node.selectSingleNode("lastname").getText());
                System.out.println("First Name : " + node.selectSingleNode("nickname").getText());
                System.out.println("Marks : " + node.selectSingleNode("marks").getText());
            }
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Текст ошибки

```
Error:(6, 17) java: package org.dom4j does not exist
Error:(7, 17) java: package org.dom4j does not exist
Error:(8, 17) java: package org.dom4j does not exist
Error:(9, 17) java: package org.dom4j does not exist
Error:(10, 20) java: package org.dom4j.io does not exist
Error:(16, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SAXReader
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
Error:(16, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SAXReader
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
Error:(17, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
Error:(21, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Element
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
Error:(23, 18) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
Error:(25, 18) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
Error:(33, 18) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DocumentException
  location: class com.tutorialspoint.xml.DOM4JParserDemo
```

То есть говорится что пакета не существует, хотя я с IDE спокойно захожу в те пакеты во внешней библиотеке и могу просматривать код.

Предполагаю что проблема возникла из-за использования Maven(но вполне вероятно что ошибаюсь).
При создании нового проекта и ручного подкючения библиотек всё хорошо работает.

При последующем подключении библиотек через Maven в том проекте всё так же нормально работает.

В старом проекте, что при ручном подключении, что при автоматическом, ошибка остается.

Знает ли кто-нибудь из-за чего возникает эта проблема и как её решить?

Answer (score 3):

Я решил проблему следующим образом: удалил с папки проекта папку .idea и файл "ProjectName".iml. После этого всё стало добавляться нормально. Но хотелось бы разобраться из-за какой настройки возникла эта проблема. Если у кого-то есть подробная информация, поделитесь пожалуйста.